# Business Central ListPart with properties from related entities to the source table

Tags: dynamics-business-central

I am working on a proof of concept. I created a new AL Project with a simple ListPart with Sales Invoice Line as its Source Table. But I need to add properties which are not part of the source table but its related entities.

My code looks like this:

```
page 50107 CustomInvoicePage
{
   PageType = ListPart;
   SourceTable = "Sales Invoice Line";
   Caption = 'Custom Sales Inovice Line';
   Editable = true;
   UsageCategory = Lists;
   ApplicationArea = All;

   layout
   {
      area(content)
      {
          repeater(Group)
          {
              field("Invoice Name"; "No.")
              {
                  ApplicationArea = All;
                  Caption = 'Invoice Name';
              }
              field("Invoice Date"; "Posting Date")
              {
                  ApplicationArea = All;
                  Caption = 'Invoice Date';
              }
              field("Product Name"; Description)
              {
                  ApplicationArea = All;
                  TableRelation = Item.Description;
                  Caption = 'Product Name';
              }
              field("Product Amount"; Amount)
              {
                  ApplicationArea = All;
                  Caption = 'Product Amount';
              }
              field("Unit Cost"; "Unit Cost")
              {
                  ApplicationArea = All;
                  Caption = 'Unit Cost';
              }
              field("Product Gross Weight"; "Gross Weight")
              {
                  ApplicationArea = All;
                  Caption = 'Product Gross Weight';
              }
              field("Sell-to Customer No."; "Sell-to Customer No.")
              {
                  ApplicationArea = All;
                  TableRelation = Customer."No.";
              }
          }
      }
   }
 }
```

I tried overriding the expression in the field with the table relation showing a property from the other entity. For an example override the Item No. property in the Sales Invoice Line with Item Durability. But that did not work and it still showed me the Item No. in the column.

Is there a way I can use parameters from the a related entity to the Sales Invoice Line for an example a property from the Item entity that is not shown in the Sales Invoice Line properties without expanding the Sales Invoice Line table with new fields ?

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to point out that the optimal solution for your problem is to create a `tableextension` for `Sales Invoice Line` where you that the required fields as `FlowFields`, which you then add to your page. It requires a lot less code and it saves you a lot of calls to the database.

Disregarding this adivce you can solve your problem by adding a global variable for e.g. `Item` to your page and then create a field that uses the variable as data source.

You will also need to retrieve the record in both `OnAfterGetRecord` and `OnAfterGetCurrRecord`.

Here is an example:

```
page 50107 CustomInvoicePage
{
    PageType = ListPart;
    SourceTable = "Sales Invoice Line";
    Caption = 'Custom Sales Inovice Line';
    Editable = true;
    UsageCategory = Lists;
    ApplicationArea = All;

    layout
    {
        area(content)
        {
            repeater(Group)
            {
                field("Item Durability"; Item.Durability)
                {
                    ApplicationArea = All;
                    Caption = 'Item Durability';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    trigger OnAfterGetRecord()
    begin
        GetItem();
    end;

    trigger OnAfterGetCurrRecord()
    begin
        GetItem();
    end;

    local procedure GetItem()
    begin
        // We need to do it this way, because not all Sales Invoice Lines are Item lines.
        if not Item.Get("No.") then
            Item.Init();
    end;

    var
        Item: Record Item;
}
```

Be aware that when using this method the source record in this case Item is not changed if a new value is entered. This would need to be handled with code as well.

**Bonus Information:**
A page with `Sales Invoice Line` as `SourceTable` can not be editable as it is not permitted to edit posted documents. If this is really what you want you need to at `Permissions` to your page for modification of `Sales Invoice Line`.

```
Permissions = tabledata "Sales Invoice Line" = m;
```